# Visual Studio is not responding while using TypeScript

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript, web-essentials

I am using the typescript. I can create simple  typescript samples and run. 
When i was creating complex type of codes, visual studio becomes not responding.

Can any of you know the reason for this issue? The Performance tab on TaskManager takes approx 35%. Can any of you aware of this issue?

Code i was implemented looks like below,

```
module myModule{
  export class myClass implements myInterface{
    // code to PartialUpdate, otalUpdate function declarations and 
    // extra properties and methods
  }
  export interface myInterface{
    PartialUpdate:void;
    TotalUpdate:void;
  }
}
```

**Note:** Visual Studio becomes not responding while creating code itself, before starting build.

I have used the following extensions:

- MicroSoft Web Developer Tools,
- Nuget Package Manager,
- TypeScript for VS 2012
- VS Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript and
- Web Essentials 2012

And my system config is

- Processor:Pentium Dual core 2.70GHZ
- RAM: 4 GB
- System type: 64 bit

Comment: What Visual Studio extensions have you got and what is your machine spec?

Comment: just now, i updated my question!

Comment: If you switch off Web Essentials, is there any improvement? The difference is that Web Essentials compiles on the fly, whereas the plain TypeScript extension only compiles on build.

Comment: When i make Web Essentials as disable visual studio is working!

Comment: That's your problem then! You might find it better to disable that until the performance is fixed if you can live without the side-by-side editing for a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using the latest version of Web Essentials 2012? <strike>(2.0 at time of writing)</strike> And of TypeScript ([0.8.1.1](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/F/2FFA1FBA-97CA-4FFB-8ED7-A4AE06398948/TypeScriptSetup.0.8.1.1.msi))? I had the same issue with an earlier combination of WE and TS 0.8.1, but it was fixed in a recent release.

WebEssentials can be configured either to compile on save, and/or on build. Go `Tools > Options > Web Essentials > TypeScript` in VS2012 and try toggling these switches and see if this helps.

Disable Web Essentials, go to the `Tools > Options` as described above, and try turning off `Compile TypeScript on save`. This way you can have all the benefits of WE without the performance hit

**Update**

WE 2012 has just ticked over to the next version: [2.1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6?SRC=VSIDE)

Comment: i was using TypeScript 0.8.1.1 only. And i have referred the same url to support TypeScript in js. FYI, i were using the web essentials which is downloaded from the given link only.

Comment: Enable Web Essentials, go to the Tools > Options as described above, and try turning off 'Compile TypeScript on save'. This way you can have all the benefits of WE without the performance hit. FYI I am working on a very complex modular project (50+ TS files and counting, up to five levels of nested AMD modules), and with the latest versions of WE and TS, everything compiles in no time.

Comment: do you need  Web Essentials 2012 if you have vs 2012?

Comment: @Nikos - WE 2012 extends the TS (and other web) capabilities of VS 2012.  The two are complementary. So no, you don't need it, but I've personally found it very useful in working with TS. Have a look at the feature set (at the link above), and see if you think it would be of benefit to you.

Comment: @JcFx nice just what I needed. Do you  know if it automatically changes your project to use 0.81? I recently installed the new typescript.

Comment: @Nikos - I've never manually changed the TS version (just installed successive releases of TS and WE). My understanding was that the VS installer for TS upgraded the version used, but I'm not sure. Anyway it seems to happen automagically.

Comment: @JcFx  hmm, I actually had to manually edit the csproj to use the .81 otherwise the compile failed

Comment: @Nikos - Probably because the TypeScriptCompile command is not referenced in my project file. I never added it manually (like this, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12681880/1014822) - I've always had WE2012 installed and it has taken care of building TS from the start.