# TypeScript in Visual Studio 2012 not compiling

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I have installed **TypeScript** (v0.9.1.1) on my Visual Studio 2012 installation but I cannot make it compile my `.ts` files during build (see screenshots below).

I have already tried a lot of different solutions posted here but none of them worked for me.

Please note that I can create a TypeScript project, the problem is that Visual Studio is not compiling/creating the `.js` file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to introduce error in your typescript file and make a build of the project. Does it show up error pane?

Also the js files are not part of the solution. Do you look for them on disk ?

Also check that your project file has following entries in it. Along the lines more less:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="app.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES3</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>false</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES3</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>true</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>false</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that my project was made with Visual Studio 2010 and so it ditn't have those lines. Now it says `The TypeScript Compiler was given an empty configurations string, which is unusual and suspicious.`, but it seems that the .js file is created. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: i would suggest to recreate the project in VS2012 with typescript add on installed. There may be a lot of thing wrong so that is your bestbet. Whatever code you have you can really simply move it to the freshly created solution.

Comment: This worked for me. I had to add the 'import' element to the bottom of the csproj file though because '$(VSToolsPath)' is initialized somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 6):

as you can see in patch notes for version 0.9.1

> The .js files are no longer part of the project by default. Starting
>   with 0.9.1, we don't nest them under the TypeScript files. This is
>   more of a visual change, but it also lets us manage the .js files
>   behind the scenes a bit cleaner.

**So just create a TypeScript file**(in your case app.ts)  **and then simply add reference to your page**

```html
<head>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by right click on the typescript file, select properties, and then set the BuildAction to none as shown here:

[image]

Comment: we should be able to compile when we build without errors. I have similar issue here. My error with "Build Action: TypeScript Compile" set is "From Output: VSTSC : tsc.js(764, 13) JavaScript runtime error : Automation server can't create object".

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have invalid TypeScript. There are some TypeScript errors that don't show up in the Error List, but they prevent TypeScript Compile-On-Save and show a `Output generation failed` message in the Visual Studio status bar.

These are the TypeScript errors that can cause this:

- `export`ing a class which is not inside of a module (v 0.9.5).

Please let me know if there are more such errors, I'll add them here.