# TypeScript not working in Visual Studio 2013 Community

Tags: typescript

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Community Update 4 and I started an empty ASP.NET 4.5 Web Site.  Now I would like to work with TypeScript but there's nothing in VS.  I tried installing it from the web site 1.3 from here : https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/955e0262-0858-40c9-ab5a-1acc680e9bfd still nothing.  I should be able to add a TypeScript file and start coding but there's no such type in ADD NEW ITEM nor writing code in a .ts file seems to know anything about TypeScript.  Am I missing something somewhere ?

Comment: Have you installed the VS updates?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680486/how-do-i-add-typescript-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-project. Either you need to configure your ASP.Net project to run TypeScript compiler on .ts files, or you need to add a separate "HTML Application with TypeScript" project, which is pre-configured for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using TypeScript in an existing Visual Studio Web Site project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867390/using-typescript-in-an-existing-visual-studio-web-site-project)

Comment: I don't have such option to add TypeScript file nor there's nothing in the TypeScript node when Creating a new project of type TypeScript.  Even after installing the 1.3 for Visual Studio 2013 so what is going on exactly ?  Do I have to reinstall VS community 2013 entirely ?

Comment: I did install VS update yes.  the VS is up to date.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1029356/typescript-integration-does-not-work-vs2013update4-comuedition-after-clean-install-from-iso

Comment: Finally I had to delete everything about TypeScript in the registry and reinstall 1.3 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all entries in the registry about TypeScript and reinstall TypeScript latest version and it worked for me.